# How to fix a c# .net framework 4.8 winforms when all events from the form just stopped running?

Tags: c#, forms, controls, disabled-control

I have an automation software which uses a simple user interface (with WinForms) on .net Framework 4.8.
It uses the default tab control, which has 7 tab pages.
Around 5 timers, and also 12 separate threads.

I do have 2 customized user controls on the project, but those are not in use.

The system works just fine.
After a period of time (it seems to be at random), in the last time I got it (the problem) it was after something about 1 to 2 hours of the system running.

The symptoms:
All the threads are running normally.
All the timers and all the other system events stopped working.
Can't click anything on the screen, nothing responds to interaction (not event the 'X' button to close the window).

There is just one event that is still working:
The double click on the systray icon, but the menu attached to it (even though it opens) can't be clicked.

All the controls in the form are "working". They all have their values and everything attached to it. They're just not running. No animation, no nothing. Just a static screen.

And no, the form isn't disabled. It is enabled and visible.

I've tried checking individually all the timers and all the events that could be triggered by the form somehow. Nothing responds (and there isn't a 'Not responding' message on the form window as usual).

Looked into all the possible angles, but no luck so far.

Comment: _" and also 12 separate threads."_ <-- That's probably your problem (are you using `Thread` directly? and if so, **why?**)

Comment: When you run into that situation attach a debugger and have a closer look.

Comment: It uses separate thread because there are too much heavy work to be dealt with at the same time. Hence the need for those 12 Threads. And yes, they are the System.Threading.Thread.

Comment: Also i'm running it from inside Visual Studio 2022 last build, on debuging mode.

Comment: @Dai why do you think the Threads would be the problem? What do they have anything to do with the it?

Comment: Because it's very easy to break WinForms by accidentally resuming on the wrong thread, or messing up the Win32 Window Message pump. Are you using `Thread.Abort` anywhere? How are you doing cross-thread synchronization? (`Join`? `WaitHandle`? etc) What kinds of work/code is happening in these other threads? Are you using any `async` code in there too? Why `new Thread` instread of `ThreadPool` or `Task.Run`? How are you managing thread lifetime? (Basically, as of 2023, _there is no good reason_ to ever use `Thread` directly: [so you have a code-smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: I see your point, but those threads don't "talk" to the form. The only time its used Thread.Abort would be on system closing. Theres no async code besides the Threads itselves. I still don't see how this would be a problem. But I will change all of them to run as a background task as you recomended. If needed I will reopen the question. Thanks for the help!